# This imacros code does not work

Tags: imacros

Source code where program need to input data:

```
<input id="last_name" type="text" data-name="lastName" autocomplete="on" tabindex="54">
```

Code that iMacros uses to input data(that works):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frm-submit ATTR=ID:last_name CONTENT=english
```

Source code where program need to input data:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" data-name="phoneNumber" autocomplete="on" tabindex="57">
```

Code that iMacros uses to input data (doesn't work):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TYPE FORM=tel:frm-submit ATTR=PHONE:phoneNumber CONTENT=3463475233
```

Comment: What, specifically, about this code, doesn't work?

Comment: Ive written in the last line the code that does not work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the syntax is incorrect based on the example above that's working.

Try this...

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frm-submit ATTR=ID:phone CONTENT=3463475233
```

Complete guess...

[Demo-FillForm](http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-FillForm)